# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm on Laravel 5.8 on a XAMPP stack.

---

Consider these two migrations to create two tables:

post_categories table.

```
Schema::create('post_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->string('name');
  $table->string('slug');
  $table->string('status');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

posts table.

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->string('name');
  $table->string('slug');
  $table->mediumText('description');
  $table->integer('views');
  $table->integer('post_category_id')->unsigned();
  $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
  $table->timestamps();

  $table->foreign('post_category_id')->references('id')->on('post_categories');
});
```

When I run `php artisan migrate`, I'm getting the following error:

> General error: 1005 Can't create table `testdb`.`#sql-38d8_102` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed").

---

I've tried running both:

- `php artisan migrate`
- `php artisan migrate:fresh`

I also tried changing the `post_category_id` field to a regular integer, instead of unsigned: no difference.

Also restarted the MySQL server and Apache service, didn't make a difference.

The `post_categories` migration runs **before** the `posts` migration. The `posts` table gets created, but the foreign key doesn't.

---

**Why is this error being thrown and how do I solve it?**

Comment: Check order of your migrations. In this case 'post_categories' should go before 'posts'... Finally try to add foreign key in next migration, while keeping,  referenced id types identical ....

Comment: My comment has nothing to do with your problem, but you forgot to references the ```user_id``` FK on your migration

Comment: @LucasPiazzi, Yes I've already added it, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might be happening because you're trying to create a foreign key with an integer field to a big integer field. In your posts migration, instead of this

```
$table->integer('post_category_id')->unsigned();
```

do this:

```
$table->bigInteger('post_category_id')->unsigned();
```

Comment: This solved it, I didn't even notice the bigIncrements field. It used to be just increments in older Laravel versions, anyway, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
$table->integer('post_category_id')->unsigned();
```

Try this:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('post_category_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error where I wanted to link two tables, users tables and deposits tables. I tried many options but they didn't work. However, this is what worked for me on create deposits migration:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```